# How to define a `SetDelay` of an interpolating function from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, functions, numerics, replacement

Basically I solved a problem, consequently I wanna define a function which uses part of that problem to use later on as a function. 
So I tried the SetDelay (:=)

```
fw[x_] := -2*Sqrt[2 x]*vCH2Cl2[x] - 4 x*Evaluate[D[f[x, 0], x] /. Sol];
```

Which yields no errors, but doesn't define a function. Then someone suggested that I just set the function with the = command. But when I define the same function as before.

```
fw[x_] = -2*Sqrt[2 x]*vCH2Cl2[x] - 4 x*Evaluate[D[f[x, 0], x] /. Sol];
```

I get the Error:

```
ReplaceAll::reps: "{Sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Since it was suggested that I add the complete try:

```
Sc = 18.7*10^(-6)/(1.2041*2.522^(-9)*301.15^1.462);
Sol = NDSolve[{
    D[f[x, η], η] == g[x, η],
    D[g[x, η], {η, 2}] + 
      f[x, η]*D[g[x, η], η] + 
      2*x*(D[g[x, η], η]*D[f[x, η], x] - 
         g[x, η]*D[g[x, η], x]) == 0,
    D[φ[x, η], {η, 2}] + 
      Sc*f[x, η]*D[φ[x, η], η] + 
      2*x*Sc*D[f[x, η], x]*D[φ[x, η], η] - 
      2*x*Sc*g[
        x, η]*(D[φ[x, η], x] + φ[
          x, η]) == 0,
    (*Boundary values*)
    (*η \[Rule] 0*)   
    f[x, 0] == 1.14267*Exp[-10000*x](*+((1-Exp[-10000*x])*fw[x])*),
    g[x, 0] == 1 - Exp[-10000 x],
    φ[x, 0] == 1 - Exp[-10000*x],
    (*x \[Rule] 0; Initial Condition, guesses from Blasius solution*)

        f[0, η] == 1.14267,
    g[0, η] == 0,
    φ[0, η] == 0,
    (*η \[Rule] ∞*)   
    g[x, 10] == 0,
    φ[x, 10] == 0},
   {f, g, φ}, (*Unknown Variables*)
   {x, 0, 
    1}, (*Range of x*)
   {η, 0, 10}, (*Range of η*)

   MaxStepSize -> 0.1, AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 3(*MaxStepSize\[Rule]0.01,AccuracyGoal\[Rule]4,
   PrecisionGoal\[Rule]4*), 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 150}}}
   ];
```

and 
vCH2Cl2[x] is basically the same thing as in my question:

```
vCH2Cl2[x_] = constant*(Evaluate[
      D[φ[x, 0], ξ] /. Sol]*(-1));
```

Comment: What is `f[x,0]`, include it in the question?

Comment: f[x,0] is part of the previewious calculation. An interpolating function from NDsolve, sry forgot to mention

Comment: @MMM Sry misread your comment xD... added it

Comment: @MMM I'm sry I'm an idiot. I tried to simplify my problem but just made it worse. So now I posted the original try. As a little sidenote: The e-Functions are there so I don't the inconsistent boundary conditions error. The singular point at the beginning unfortunatly is problem related.

Thanks for the help so far though. I can see you are really trying

Comment: Is this a non-similar system and you want to plot ` D[φ[x, 0], ξ] vs x`?

Comment: @MMM Yeah unfortunatly it is. I don't want to plot it, that was different question (Thanks again for that, btw ;)), but I would like to use the values, in my function for ongoing calculations. Ultimately I would like to define a function as fw[x] (as stated above) which I can use as a boundary value lateron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that what you are looking for is `With`:

```
With[{dd = D[f[x, 0], x]},
  SetDelayed @@ Hold[ff[x_], -5*dd]
]
```

which is the standard way to insert evaluated expressions into held expressions as the RHS of a `SetDelayed`. Unfortunately `SetDelayed` is a scoping construct and will try to protect the `x` it uses as argument from the one used in the expression we insert. Thus we need an additional trick and only let `SetDelayed` see the `x`es after we inserted the expression. `Evaluate` will only work when it is a direct argument of a function/symbol with a `Hold` attribute.

If you find this complicated, yes it is. But the good news is that it is not necessary to go through all those evaluation order and scoping complications if we slightly raise the level of abstraction: the solution of a differential equation is a function, so when we extract those functions, we can work with them without ever being bothered with naming their arguments. Here is how you would do that (I'm leaving out the details in the code below which can be copied from the OPs question):

```
{fsol,gsol,φsol} = {f,g,φ} /. NDSolveValue[{
        D[f[x, η], η] == g[x, η],...},...},
        {f,g,φ},{x,0,1},{η, 0, 10},...]
```

In newer versions we have `NDSolveValue`, which which makes extraction of solutions functions even easier:

```
{fsol,gsol,φsol}=NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, η], η] == g[x, η],...},},
        {f,g,φ},{x,0,1},{η, 0, 10},...]
```

Either way, N`fsol`, `gsol` and `φsol` will now hold the solution interpolating functions.

For an `InterpolatingFunction` you can get derivatives as another `InterpolatingFunction` for the complete domain like that:

```
dφdx = Derivative[1,0][φsol]
```

Now the variable `dφdx` holds the derivative of the solution with respect to its first argument. Note how well this matches the mathematical abstraction that the derivative of a function is another function, no arguments ever involved, no complications of passing, defining or even naming arguments.

If you go this path, you will find that it is one of the lucky cases where more elegant code does not only create clearer code but also more efficient one. You can of course use `dφdx` like a function with arguments, and e.g. plot it like this:

```
Plot[dφdx[x,0],{x,0,1}]
```

With that, we can define `vCH2Cl2` like this (again making `vCH2Cl2` another "mathematical" function):

```
With[{dφdx = dφdx,constant=N[Pi](*or whatever it is*)},
  vCH2Cl2 = Function[x,constant*(dφdx[x, 0]*(-1))]
]
```

This uses the same trick as above to insert the evaluated `dφdx` into the unevaluated body of the `Function` to which we set the variable `vCH2Cl2`. `Function` also is a scoping construct, but as we insert a function with no arguments, there is no scoping problem now. Thus the following would also work for the same reasons:

```
ClearAll[vCH2Cl2]
With[{dφdx = dφdx,constant=N[Pi](*or whatever it is*)},
  vCH2Cl2[x_] := constant*(dφdx[x, 0]*(-1));
]
```

But again I think the first version better matches the abstraction that we are manipulating "mathematical functions" as objects than the second and will make further manipulation or passing around of these functions easier.

Answer (score 6):

The interpolating functions can be called separatly as `SetDelay` like this

```
f11[x_, η_] := (f /. Sol[[1, 1]])[x, η];    
g11[x_, η_] := (g /. Sol[[1, 2]])[x, η];    
p11[x_, η_] := (φ /. Sol[[1, 3]])[x, η];
```

Now plotting the `SetDelay`

```
Plot3D[{f11[x, η], g11[x, η], p11[x, η]}, {x, 0,1}, {η, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

The function of single variable can be defined like this

```
fw[x_] := D[p11[x, η], η] /. η -> 0;

fw[0.1]
```

> -0.0996175

and finally, plotting it

```
Plot[fw[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

#### Update by m_goldberg

Here is a refinement to MMM's answer that is more robust and more efficient.

This gets the interpolating functions from the solution and gives them names so they may be referenced like any other functions. No substitution is necessary, especially no substitution at every call as happens with `f11, g11` and `p11`.

```
{fF, gF, φF} = Sol[[1, All, 2]];
Plot3D[{fF[u, v], gF[u, v], φF[u, v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Here, substitution is used, but only once. `Block` protects the variables `x` and `u` from any previously made global assignments.

```
x = 42; u = 43;
Block[{x, u}, fw[x_] = D[φF[x, u], u] /. u -> 0;]
Plot[fw[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The plots give the same images as shown by MMM.

Comment: If I could I would hug you right now. I have been struggeling with this for the better part of the last 3 weeks! Thanks!

Comment: @M.Pow Happy to help. Ask freely here but please first be sure about your question and describe it clearly.

Comment: @m_goldberg What exactly do you mean by that? (sry kind of new and interessted)

Comment: @m_goldberg I like you to edit my attempt and add your part for the benefit of new users. If you don't mind?

Comment: Ok, I'll add an update.