# How do I integrate this solution from NDSolve over $v$, to plot in $x,t$ plane?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

The function `f[x, v, t]` is the following numerical solution:

```
NDSolve[{
   D[f[x,v, t], t] == v*D[f[x,v, t], x] + D[f[x,v, t], v, v], 
   f[x,v, 0] == Exp[(-v^2 - x^2)/(2*0.001^2)]/(0.001*Sqrt[2 Pi]), 
   f[x,-100, t] == 0, f[x,100, t] == 0, f[100,v, t] == 0
  }, 
 f,
 {v, -100.0, 100.0}, {t, 0.0, 50.0}, {x, -100.0, 100.0}]
```

How do I obtain $$q(x,t)=\int_{-100}^{100} f(x,v,t)dv$$

I wish to plot this function in the $x,t$ plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code, doesn't work, I wrote my own simplified version:

```
g[x_,t_] = NDSolveValue[{
  D[f[x, t], t] == D[f[x, t], {x, 2}]
  , f[x, 0] == Sin[x]
  , f[0, t] == 0, f[π, t] == 0
 }
 , f[x, t]
 , {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

Note that I am using `NDSolveValue` to spit out the function automatically. You can then directly integrate the function:

```
integratedG[t_] = Integrate[g[x, t], {x, 0, 1}];
```

and the result is another interpolating function that you can then plot. The reason that this works is that behind the scenes, an `InterpolatingFunction` consists of a bunch of polynomials, which are obviously easy to analytically integrate, and *Mathematica* does that automatically.

Alternatively, if you don't need the function itself, you can build this directly into the call to `NDSolveValue`:

```
integratedG[t_] = NDSolveValue[{
   D[f[x, t], t] == D[f[x, t], {x, 2}]
   , f[x, 0] == Sin[x]
   , f[0, t] == 0
   , f[π, t] == 0}
  , Integrate[f[x0, t], {x0, 0, 1}]
  , {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

---

To wit:

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Thx! Indeed I have a typo in the equation above, will correct it.

Answer (score 3):

When working with solutions that come out of `NDSolve` I would always suggest to understand the resulting `InterpolatingFunction`s as a representation of a function in the mathematical sense and handle it as a value, not a function in a programmatic sense. To make clear what I am trying to say see this slightly modified version of *march*s nice answer:

```
fsol = NDSolveValue[{
    D[f[x, t], t] == D[f[x, t], {x, 2}]
    , f[x, 0] == Sin[x]
    , f[0, t] == 0, f[π, t] == 0
  }
  , f
  , {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 5}];
```

This directly gets the result as a function, (no arguments involved!).

Integrating that with respect to one of its arguments is of course simple, what we expect to get back is another "mathematical" function:

```
Integrate[fsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]
```

what we get back is again an `InterpolatingFunction`, but unfortunately this time we have an argument attached. Does that match the idea of a mathematical function? I don't think so, so lets extract the real function:

```
fIntegrated = Block[{t}, Head@Integrate[fsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

the `Block` is not stricktly necessary, but it saves us from any problems which could occure if `t` would happen to have a definition. The advantages of that approach becomes even clearer when you need a derivative:

```
fDerivative = Derivative[1,0][fsol]
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @m_goldberg for his [idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137276/how-to-define-a-setdelay-of-an-interpolating-function-from-ndsolve/137281#137281).

The PDE in question cannot be handle directly by `NDSolve`. So we need to specify a `Method`. For this, I used `MethodOfLines`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[f[x, v, t], t] ==v*D[f[x, v, t], x] + D[f[x, v, t], v, v], 
   f[x, v, 0] == Exp[(-v^2 - x^2)/(2*0.001^2)]/(0.001*Sqrt[2 Pi]), 
   f[x, -100, t] == 0, f[x, 100, t] == 0, f[100, v, t] == 0}, 
  f, {v, -100.0, 100.0}, {t, 0.0, 50.0}, {x, -100.0, 100.0}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> {30, 30}}, "TemporalVariable" -> t}];
```

Now extracting the interpolating function for external use,

```
{fF} = sol[[1, All, 2]];
Plot3D[fF[x, v, 1], {x, -100.0, 100.0}, {v, -100.0, 100.0}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Integrating the interpolating function,

```
Block[{x, t}, q[x_, t_] = Integrate[fF[x, v, t], {v, -100, 100}];]
Plot3D[q[x, t], {x, -100.0, 100.0}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

The above plot doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, however -  is there a way to increase the precision of the numerics? For very simple examples (like a 2d diffusion equation) I get results which make no sense (as you point out) , e.g., negative values for f etc.. Is there a better way instead of "method of lines" for example?

Comment: "NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 50.50404534329911` at t = 1.` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options."